# How to add an interpunct to an x axis label

Tags: r, symbols, axis-labels

I have been trying to format this axis for a graph using this line of code:

`xlab= bquote('Titratable Acidity'~(g•L^-1))`

although I continually receive an error with the "•" symbol cannot be added. I have also tried the following unicode as well with a similar error:

```
xlab= bquote('Titratable Acidity'~(g"\U00B7"L^-1))
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the "•" symbol in my x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
plot(0,0, xlab = expression(Titratable~Acidity~(g*"\U00B7"*L^-1)))
```

[image]

---

Or,

```
plot(0,0, xlab = expression(Titratable~Acidity~(g*"\U2022"*L^-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that second code worked perfectly! Thank you very much.